# Support related to Mplus code: Saving class variable of second step pf BCH estimation

Tags: .net

I followed Mplus Web Notes No. 21 (v11) and worked with the following codes to the SECOND step estimation of the BCH method for getting the class variable to be saved in my file. All other variables are saved but not the class variable. Can you please advise me where is wrong in this code? Mplus team did not support because my Mplus license has not included technical support. My code is as follows.

````
       Usevar=  Y1     female      x1    x2  BCHW1 -BCHW3;
         classes = C3(3);     
       Training= BCHW1      BCHW2 BCHW3(bch);
       Idvariable = A0;
       Analysis:
       Type = mixture;  starts=100 9;
       Model:
       %Overall%
       C3 on    female      x1    x2  ;
       Y1 on    female      x1    x2  ;
       %C3#1%
       Y1 on    female      x1    x2  ;
             %C3#2%
       Y1 on    female      x1    x2  ;
                     %C3#3%
      Y1 on    female      x1    x2  ;
       output:tech8 ;
       savedata: file is C:/Dha/jessie/2ndStC2.dat  ;```

`INPUT READING TERMINATED NORMALLY`


My OUTPUT SAVED as follows:
````

````
    Save file
    C:/Dha/jessie/2ndStC2.dat  ;
    Order and format of variables
    Y1        F10.3
    female    F10.3
    x1        F10.3
    x2        F10.3
   BCHW1     F10.3
   BCHW2     F10.3
   BCHW3     F10.3
   A0        I5
  Save file format
  9F10.3 I5 ```
````

The class variable (C3) could not be saved with the code. Can anybody help me where is the error in the code?
Thanks.
Sincerely.
B. Dhak